# How to get parent's data when its own data is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've a list like this:

```
+ID+--+ParentID+--+Name+--+Code
+1-----NULL--------A-------Aa
+2-----NULL--------B-------Bb
+3-----2-----------B1------NULL
+4-----2-----------B2------NULL
+5-----1-----------A2------NULL
```

I get 'Code' values to another list by a linq query.

```
var newList = new List<string>();
list.ForEach(x=>newList.Add(x.Code))
```

However, if the **Code** is null or empty, I want to get its parent's 'Code'. So, my new list should contains

```
+Aa
+Bb
+Bb
+Bb
+Aa
```

How can I do this with linq?

Comment: any attempts on your own?

Comment: is the order in `newList` important? shall it reflect the order of the items in `list`?

Comment: Yes I tried some code. But they were spaghetti. And yes, order is important

Comment: why not sharing your spaghetti, may be you hit someones taste

Comment: Does it have to be recursive (multi levels) or we need to only consider immediate parent as obviously the solution would not be the same. Does it have to be done in Linq or SQL or C# code is also OK? Also can the table be big enough to consider performance impact?

Comment: If you don't show what you tried people will think you just want them to write your code. Show your own efforts and explain why they fall short. That clarifies what you're actually asking. It would have improved may of your previous questions. Try to adhere to it and you'll notice that you get more pointed answers --and quicker.

Answer (score 1):

This query gets what you need:

```
var q = from x in list
        let y = list.FirstOrDefault(z => z.ID == x.ParentID)
        select (x.Code != null ? x.Code : y.Code);
```

This query assumes that if any item's code is null, it has a parent. Otherwise you'll get null reference exception.